# Use C library in C++

Tags: c++, .net, c, visual-studio

I have C library with a header file. Now i want to make a wrapper in C++ in order to use it in .NET. When i include the library, the compiler reports an syntax errors regarding the variable types (DWORD, LPCSTR, etc...). 
In short, probably it thinks that the library is in C++ instead of C.

I tried

```
extern "C"{

  #include "c_lib.h"

}
```

but with no success. I am using Visual Studio 2010, so maybe so changes to the project settings should be done.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: `DWORD` and `LPCSTR` have nothing to do with C++.  You're probably missing a header file.

Comment: Are you going to wrap it with C++/CLR? If not, why can't you just import the C function signatures?

Comment: You _do_ include `<windows.h>` first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to include `<windows.h>`, but I think you're doing it wrong. You don't need to create a C++ wrapper to use the library from .NET. You can `DllImport` all the C functions you need to call, directly in C#.

[Using the DllImport Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to everybody, i used empty project so windows.h was not included, also C++ wrapper in my case was not the best solution so i end up using DLLImport directive.